# CCSprite from local file draws as black

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, uiimage, ccsprite

Got a strange problem while working on my next app. I need to download user profile image (png file) from a server and add it as a CCSprite. Downloading works perfect. But when I want to make a CCSprite from this image I got black square (I must admit that this square has correct dimensions: 100x100). So what is wrong with this image? How can I correct image properties to make a CCSprite from it?

Im using kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888 as a DefaultAlphaPixelFormat.

EDIT:
I've uploaded this png file to a dropbox folder (temporary) so you can test it by yourself.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/52921941/profilePicture.png

Comment: can you display the PNG in another program (i.e., on you Mac)? Could you display it as a UIImage through `imageNamed`?

Comment: Yes, image opens without errors in Photoshop etc. Tried to add image to a bundle and add sprite like [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"filename"] and result is the same black square with correct dimensions. It's seems something wrong with image parameters...

Comment: And yes, it works fine when I create a UIImage, then create UIImageView and add UIImageView as [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubwiev:myUIImageView];

Comment: are you specifying the `png` extension with "filename"?

Comment: got us some code? Especially how you download the image and how you load it. Keep in mind that cocos2d only loads images from the app bundle, if you want to load an image from appdata or documents you have to specify the full path!